# can we access other fragment layout from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

[[rootView is for this fragment and rootView1 is for another fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZX5.png)

can i use the other fragment layout in the given fragment. I have tried to use it. And no error has occourd but, when I get value from the other fragments layout's editText. It is showing null. Plzz explain what to do.

Comment: No you can't, this is how you should do it: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Please add the relevant code in the question itself rather giving the image link. In the image what you have done is inflating layouts in view...so rootView and rootView1 are the reference variables to view...now if you return one of the view from onCreateView then that view becomes view for that fragment..but if you want to modify view in second fragment then it should be done via Activity only

Answer (score 1):

The archetypal way to communicate between `Fragment`s is to use an `interface` that goes via the `Activity` it is attached to. For example (code adapted from the Android Docs [Communicating With Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)):

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    FragmentOneCallback mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface FragmentOneCallback {
        public String requestMessageFromFragmentTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallback = (FragmentOneCallback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentOneCallback");
        }
    }
}
```

Later in your code, you would use something like `myTextView.setText(mCallback.requestMessageFromFragmentTwo())`

A sample implementation for your `Activity` could be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentOne.FragmentOneCallback {

    //...

    @Override
    public String requestMessageFromFragmentTwo() {
        String message = "";
        FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_two_tag");
        if (fragmentTwo != null) message = fragmentTwo.getMessage();
        return message;
    }
```

And `FragmentTwo`:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    //...

    public String getMessage() {
        return "This would be your message!";
    }
}
```

Here's a [link to a sample app](https://github.com/PPartisan/FragmentInterfaceExample) I put together for a similar SO question that may be of use to you.